# Wrong depiction of screen on Android 5.0 Lollipop

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

We've updated our phone to 5.0 and now our App looks "sometimes" like the image show below. Sometimes mean that when we open the App it's looks nice, but when we start another Activity (or swipe - we use a ViewPager) we sometimes see that. But sometimes not... But to often to not to ignore that :/

Thats very curious. We haven't make any changes on our App. Since 5.0 it's like that. But only on Phones (Nexus 5) and 7"-Inch Tablets (Nexus 7) (which we use as "Phones"). On 10"-Inch Tablets, like the Nexus 10, we haven't any problems like that.

I don't now what we can do... So.. what can we do?! :)

€dit: Have make a AOSP-Bugreport too: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80203&thanks=80203&ts=1416496254

[image]

Comment: To me this is related to Lollipop itself and not to your application. All the other applications are working fine?

Comment: Yes, other applications are fine. But "the other" Applications are only Google-Apps. No Third-Party Apps (without ours) are installed...

Comment: I have also experienced this but in the background of a dialog. In my theme I was setting `android:dialogTheme` to a style with parent `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog`. When removed it stopped happening, I suspect it's a Lollipop bug...

Comment: It was actually setting `android:windowBackground` to the color white in my dialog theme that caused the issue for me, however I don't understand why this would be a problem.

Comment: Removed all our Lollipop styles from AppCompact to "old" Holo.Light and same effect...it's very bad :(

Comment: I think they have fixed it in 5.1...